# AWS Log Insights Query - Filter Begins with specific IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Is it possible to query log insights data and filter based on IP addresses that start with specific values.  The query below is returning too much data... In addition to returning data that begin with 98, it is also returning data with IP addresses that have 98 in the middle of the string.

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log
| filter (event.src_ip like /98./) 
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the answer using Regular Expressions.  I needed to use the ^ character at the beginning of the expression.

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log
| filter (event.src_ip like /^98./) 
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same approach to find entries where `event.src_ip` begins with `10.` (such as private IPs), you will match IPs starting with `108.`. This is because `.` matches any character in regex.

Instead, you should escape the `.` character, so your query ends up looking like this:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log
| filter (event.src_ip like /^98\./)
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Explanation:

- `^` match the start of the IP address - this avoids matching the rest of the expression mid-way through a given IP address
- `98` match literal "98"
- `\.` match the literal "." - this avoids matching any character, as the unescaped `.` would.